# div inner html using c sharp static method? how to

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I have a static method where I want to get the "div" inner html I Used the following method

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string SetFileNameU(List<string> someValues)
    {
    string linkmain =   link.Replace("Journey=R", "Journey="+journey);

     SearcResult src = new SearcResult();
     src.iframesourceType(linkmain);
 return linkmain;

    }
```

and here i called non static function passing link to that fucntion

```
  public void iframesourceType(string linksrc) 
    {
        frame.InnerHtml = ""; //// error frame is null

    }
```

and returns the error

> object refrence not set to initialization of object

my html frame is div

```
     <div runat="server" id= "frame"  class="col-md-9">
               <%--<iframe class="ifr" >

                </iframe>--%>
            </div>
```

kindly tell me how to change content my webform class is searchresult.cs and frame.innerHtml was working at form laod and can be aceesed but calling from static after ajax call in non static function it works

**why static?**

1-first time when i open file i use that

```
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            string link = Convert.ToString(Session["url"]);
            Label1.Text = link;
            SomewhereInTheCode();
            frame.InnerHtml = (" <iframe class='ifr' frameborder='0'  src='" + link + "' > </iframe>");

    }
```

now i am using ajax call to web method to change inner HTML as needed see the code at top and it work only at page load

div is runat server so acesed from server side as frame

Comment: You already wrote the problem in the comments `error frame is null`

Comment: actually frame is a div i am posting html too see

Comment: so it wil never be null

Comment: @Guy you peoples are officialy guys nnobody at rescue

Comment: Why did you mark your method as a WebMethod? And why does it need to be static instead of an instance method?

Comment: The error is on your `frame` variable in the code, not the html.

Comment: check explainaion i am updatting

Comment: so how to get the aleady used instance of div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Cannot access any of the form elements in a static method. Only instanciable methods can access it.

If you want to change the content of div through web method just return the content and then assign the HTML to div in the success function of Ajax Call.

Ajax Function

```
  $.ajax({
     url     : "FileName.aspx/SetFileNameU",
     method  : "GET"/"POST",
     data    : "{someValues:['value1','value2','value3']}",
     success : function (data) {
        $('#frame').html(data);
     } 
  });
```